How to handle YouTube Data API v3 Error 429, Too many Requests (Resource has been exhausted)
I'm trying to create a playlist on YouTube using the YouTube Data API v3 in my React application. However, I'm encountering a 429 error indicating that my resource has been exhausted. To handle this, I've implemented an exponential backoff strategy with randomized delays, but I'm still hitting the rate limit. Here is my current implementation:
My code
``import axios from "axios";

// Helper function to generate a random delay within a range
const getRandomDelay = (min, max) =>
  Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;

const exponentialBackoff = async (fn, retries = 3, delay = 1000) => {
  try {
    return await fn();
  } catch (error) {
    if (
      retries > 0 &&
      error.response &&
      (error.response.status === 403 || error.response.status === 429)
    ) {
      const randomDelay = getRandomDelay(delay, delay * 2);
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, randomDelay));
      return exponentialBackoff(fn, retries - 1, delay * 2);
    } else {
      throw error;
    }
  }
};

export const createYouTubePlaylist =
  (playlistName) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const { youtubeAccessToken } = getState().auth;

    const createPlaylist = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.post(
          "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists",
          {
            snippet: {
              title: playlistName, // Remove quotes around playlistName
              description: "Playlist created from Spotify",
            },
            status: {
              privacyStatus: "public",
            },
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${youtubeAccessToken}`,
              Accept: "application/json",
            },
            params: {
              part: "snippet,status",
            },
          }
        );
        console.log("Created Playlist:", response.data);
        return response.data;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error creating YouTube playlist:", error);
        throw error; // Rethrow the error to handle it outside
      }
    };

    return exponentialBackoff(createPlaylist)
      .then((data) => {
        console.log("Playlist created successfully:", data);
        return data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error creating YouTube playlist:", error);
        return null; // Return null or handle the error as needed
      });
  };`
`


Error: 429 Resource has been exhausted


Is my exponential backoff strategy implemented correctly for handling 429 errors?
Are there any additional steps I can take to avoid hitting the rate limit?
Is there a better way to handle these errors or a recommended approach for working with the YouTube Data API v3?

